# Create Formatter class in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, formatter

I need to create a Formatter class like the following one:

```
echo \Yii::t('app', 'You are here for {n,duration} already!', ['n' => 47]);
```

For example if I wrote down :

```
echo \Yii::t('app', 'click here to open user profile {label,link}!', ['label' => $username,'href'=>"/userid?id=".$userId]);
```

it will print out a link which lead to user profile page.

Answer (score 0):

No need to extend class for this task.

Wrap translation with link like so:

```
$translation = \Yii::t('app', 'click here to open user profile ({label})!', ['label' => $username]);

<?= Html::a($translation, ['userid', 'id' => $userId]) ?>
```

Comment: thanks, but for some reason i want to combines both of them together.